Was Deuteronomy 18:15, interpreted messianically in Judaism?
Deuteronomy 18:15 “The Lord your God will raise up for you a prophet like me from among you, from your brethren—him you shall heed— 16 just as you desired of the Lord your God at Horeb on the day of the assembly, when you said, ‘Let me not hear again the voice of the Lord my God, or see this great fire any more, lest I die.’ 17 And the Lord said to me, ‘They have rightly said all that they have spoken. 18 I will raise up for them a prophet like you from among their brethren; and I will put my words in his mouth, and he shall speak to them all that I command him. 19 And whoever will not give heed to my words which he shall speak in my name, I myself will require it of him.
anywhere is it mentioned, that Deuteronomy 18, has a future messianic application ?

NOPE!! Another Christian prooftext taken out of context!!
Back up to verse 9, and read it in context. Prophecy is clearly being offered as a routine alternative to the Canaanites' various fortune-telling practices. And this is Moses telling them what to do when they enter the land, i.e. starting a few days after his death. Not about something that would happen over a millennium later.

When you enter the land, don't do horrible things like those nations do -- no putting kids through fire, or sorcery, or divination ... or inquiring of the dead ... God finds all that despicable. Just have faith in God. Those people would use all sorts of diviners and sorcerers, but that's not what God set up for you: [when you have a question about the future], God will send you a prophet from your brethren, just like I was, and listen to him. [And not to a soothsayer, augur, or whatnot.]

If you look at any of the classical Jewish lists of commandments (such as Maimonides), the commandments here are counted as:

Do not put kids through fire
Do not inquire of the dead
Do not fortune-tell by these various other Canaanite ways
Do follow the guidance of a prophet.

None of these were one-time commandments; they are constant ones.
As Rabbi Tuvia Singer has pointed out; there is no commandment "go listen to the Messiah", nor does there need to be. There's already a commandment to listen to any appropriate prophecy (which applied to Moses, Nathan, Ido, Elijah, Isaiah, Jeremiah, etc.). Nor is there a commandment "go accept a Messiah when he arrives" because we believe it will be so blazingly obvious, it would be like a command "believe that your right hand is your right hand."
